# Easy one-liner for bash/linux, to check if a PNG is valid?

Tags: linux, bash, png

`pngcheck` is almost perfect. But in its simplest form, `pngcheck` outputs a line beginning with either `OK:` or `ERROR:`. This means I have to parse an output string, and I would rather just check a return value.

I looked at the `pngcheck.c` source code, and a thorough check for PNG validity is quite the ordeal - much more than just a magic number check. So the best I can do at the moment, is to create a simple `pngcheck.sh` which calls `pngcheck` and parses the output string, followed by `exit 0` or `exit 1` accordingly.

But I wanted to check if there is an easy or more 'bashonic' solution.

Thanks!

Comment: You have the source, why not just modify it to exit 0 or 1 for valid/invalid and recompile?

Comment: running `$?` after running `pngcheck` does not work? Sorry, just want to make sure I completely understand.

Comment: How about `if [[ $(pngcheck command | grep -c ERROR) != "0" ; then echo "PNG is not valid" ; fi` for a one-liner?

Comment: bluerojo - didn't see this comments till I read the answers, but indeed, I did not even think to check status codes. I like the `| grep -c` trick for checking the result string though! Seems like a nice trick, when you simply have to parse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I look in the source code of pngcheck.c (PNGcheck, version 2.3.0 of 7 July 2007), I believe it does set the return code.  Near the end of main( ):

```
717   if (num_errors > 0)
718     err = (num_errors > 127)? 127 : (num_errors < 2)? 2 : num_errors;
719   else if (num_warnings > 0)
720     err = 1;
...
```

num_errors is the number of files that failed, num_warnings is the number of files that had a warning.  Then it exits with "return err;"

So the return code is 0 for all ok, 1 for warnings only, and 2 or higher is the number of files that failed (max 127).

And that is also consistent with the small test I did on the binary installed on Ubuntu.

```
pngcheck -q /etc/profile >/dev/null; echo $?    # returns 2
pngcheck -q cpu50.png >/dev/null;  echo $?      # returns 0
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I accepted this answer over Arkadiusz Drabczyk's, because this answer used the `-q` flag, plus the detail from source on the different status codes is nice. I guess `pngcheck` returns 2 even if only one file fails, but that's ok.

Answer (score 7):

After looking at the source code I think that you can just use `$?`
that holds exit status of the previous command in many shells. See
line 4684 in `pngcheck.c` where success message is printed. If there was
error `global_error` wouldn't be set to 0 and would be passed to and
returnd by `main()`. Things got easy now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

if pngcheck "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo things went ok
else
    echo things went bad
fi
```

Usage:

```
$ ./check-png.sh /usr/share/icons/HighContrast/22x22/status/touchpad-disabled.png
things went ok
$ ./check-png.sh /tmp/FILE
things went bad
```

Comment: It looks like `pngcheck` has a `-q` option to be quiet.  Unfortunately, it may not be totally quiet.

Comment: It seems that `-q` only suppresses `stdout` but not `stderr` but I didn't check the code.

Comment: Thank you! It did not occur to me that the status code would be set, in addition to an error message being printed. I am guessing that is a common bash/*nix idiom - to return a status code, but also to print some text, which can always be redirected to `/dev/null` if undesired,